# Laravel 5.1 file upload unique name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

My controller code where i store the file name into a database table and also moving the file to a folder.

The issue is that i am storing the original name of a file in database table, in contrast i am moving files with `uniqueid()` and `time()` . It will arise issues in future. because in database table file name and moved file are with different names.

What i want is to store the file name into database table and move the file to folder with  with `uniqueid()` and `time()`.

Code :

```
if(Input::hasFile('profile_pic')){
            $pic = Input::file('profile_pic');
            $mobile->photo1 = $pic[0]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo2 = $pic[1]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo3 = $pic[2]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo4 = $pic[3]->getClientOriginalName();
            $mobile->photo5 = $pic[4]->getClientOriginalName();

                foreach ($pic as $k=>$file){
                    if(!empty($file)){
                        $file->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', time() . uniqid() . '-' . $k . '-laptop');
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: and where is the code that stores the files in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store the destination path into a variable and then reuse it to move the file and to store its value in the database

```
if(Input::hasFile('profile_pic')){
        $pic = Input::file('profile_pic');
        $mobile->photo1 = $pic[0]->getClientOriginalName();
        $mobile->photo2 = $pic[1]->getClientOriginalName();
        $mobile->photo3 = $pic[2]->getClientOriginalName();
        $mobile->photo4 = $pic[3]->getClientOriginalName();
        $mobile->photo5 = $pic[4]->getClientOriginalName();

            foreach ($pic as $k=>$file){
                if(!empty($file)){
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/', time() . uniqid() . '-' . $k . '-laptop';
                    $file->move($destinationPath);
                    // and you may store the path here to the database
                    // like yourObject->filePath = $destinationPath;
                    // yourObject->save();
                }
            }
    }
```